# how to optimize hashmap by setting initialsize and loadFactor

Tags: java, hashmap, load-factor

I am getting data from Db and storing into Hashmap with 10,000 entries and some times I dont know the size of resultSet. I want to optimize the HashMap. so that it didn't reHash the entire hashmap by setting loadFactor and IntialSize. I know that in Consturctor of HashMap as HashMap(IntialSize,LoadFactor). can we set after getting the size of resultSet.

Same code like this.

```
HashMap<String, UserDetails> userHashMap = new HashMap<String, UserDetails>();
while (rs.next()) {
    String Id = rs.getString("id");
    String Name = rs.getString("name");
    String address = rs.getString("address");
    UserDetails userEntries = new UserDetails(id, name, addresss);

    userHashMap.put(Id, UserEntries);
}
return UserHashMap;
```

Comment: Please follow conventions and start with lowercase for variables

Comment: I've done this occasionally. In general I'd assume you'd be better off avoiding re-hashing, which would mean sizing your map so that it's larger than the expected size * load factor, but best would be to put together a few microbenchmarks and test it for yourself.

Comment: @SteveB. question is can we resize after size of resultSet as HashMap is declare the outsize of resultSet scope.

Comment: The map will resize as you attempt to insert beyond its current capacity. The value of setting an initial size is in minimizing these operations. I don't see anything in the api which would allow you to reset the load factor, which makes sense, as it would probably require you to rehash the whole table, which is exactly what you're trying to avoid. See here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html.

Comment: exactly if I know the size then we can do by setting in Consturctor but in this  case how to do?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to use the constructor?

Comment: can we set  intitialSize and LoadFactory after getting the resultSet size as it declare outside scope.

Comment: if you can leave with almost empty `HashMap` size it so that **size x load_factor >= max_expected_result_size**. If not, size it at your average case and live with resizing. Keep in mind that HashTable expansion does not necessary mean re-hashing. HashTable will make best effort to keep the hash values unchanged when expanding.

Comment: by default it is already there, and initial size is 16 and load Factor is 0.75, so when the size of list goes to 11. it will increase the size and rehash entire.